# Larger numbers in calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator

I have written a calculator in C language and everything works well except for when I try to multiply 99999999*99999999 [eight nines by eight nines]. It automatically rounds them to 100 000 000.0 and obviously, I don't want that to happen. I'm using float for numbers and precision up to .1. I tried changing float to double, but it won't work anyway. I have heard something about %g, yet I have found no information about it and I'm not sure how to make it work. Any help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT**
this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
char op;
float numberone,numbertwo;
printf("Enter the operation: ");
scanf("%f%c%f\n", &numberone, &op, &numbertwo);
switch(op) {
    case '+':
        printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f",numberone, numbertwo, numberone+numbertwo);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%.1f - %.1f = %.1f",numberone, numbertwo, numberone-numbertwo);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%.1f * %.1f = %.1f",numberone, numbertwo, numberone*numbertwo);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(numbertwo==0){
            printf("You cannot divide by zero.");
        }
        else{
        printf("%.1f / %.1f = %.1f",numberone, numbertwo, numberone/numbertwo);}
        break;
    case'^':
        printf("%f ^ %f = %f", numberone, numbertwo, pow(numberone,numbertwo));
        break;

    default:
        printf("Error! operator is not correct");
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

and when I multiply 99999999*99999999, the result is : 100 000 000.0*100 000 000.0 = 10 000 000 000 000 000.0.

Comment: how about `long long`?

Comment: Can you show the code that "_rounds_" the number?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Neither `float` nor `double` have sufficient significant decimals to contain the correct sum `9999999800000001`. This has nothing to do with *rounding*.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have tried long long, but it's still not working.

Comment: @iharob just posted the code!

Comment: @sharon i have just posted the code, hope it clears things up!

Comment: @Pauline if you have compiler support, you may try `long double`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Jongware has just suggested it, but I tried and still nothing works. It's one of my tasks on programming lessons and I'm a total beginner, so I think the answer should be simple, yet when I change types, it's not working.

Comment: @pauline `long double` representation is _mostly_ compiler dependent. I'm also not very sure. you can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) for more info.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thank you, but now it works! at least I hope so. I ended up using double and %lf. I don't know why the other ways didn't work, but I'm glad I finally have it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will work with those values, just use `double` precision, `scanf` has to use the `%lf` format specifier in that case. If you want much bigger values you will have to learn [libgmp](https://gmplib.org/) as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: thank you so much, I think it finally works! that's amazing, cause installing this whole library was too much for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
            float x, y;
            scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);
            printf("%f\n", x*y);
            return 0;
    }
```

,

```
    $ ./c
    99999999 99999999
    10000000272564224.000000
```

Do you mean the value is not exact ? This always happens with floating point numbers. 32 bit floats will be precise only up to ~6 decimal digits, while doubles will be ~15 decimal digits.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: For funsies I tried `long double` but it seems my current `gcc` has problems with it - or maybe I'm just doing something wrong. Can you try it? It may even be the answer the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A floating point number (`float`, `double` or `long double`) store numbers as mantissa and exponent (like 3x10^15, for example, but a bit different and in binary). Therefore you are bound to lose some precision bigger than decimals (= different integer if you convert it back) if you store too big integers.

If you want to handle really big numbers, you can use an arbitrary precision arithmetic library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You hit the problem of precision inherent to all standard types. They are represented in a defined number of bits. For the integers (char, short, int, long, long long) when you overflow you pass negative (or 0 for unsigned). Ex for char (8 bits) : 126 + 3 gives ... -127

For the floats (float, double, long double) it may be more subtle, because they are represented as a number of bits for the significand part and some other bits for the exponent part (see more details on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). In practice single floats can represent numbers as big as 10<sup>38</sup>, but with no more than 7 or 8 decimal digits in precision.

If you really want to do exact computations with big numbers, you should use *multiple precision* technics or directly use the excellent [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) library.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you could use the libgmp if you need to deal with large numbers. Simplified example based on your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void){
    char op;

    mpz_t x;
    mpz_t y;
    mpz_t result;
    printf("Enter the operation: ");
    scanf("%c\n", &op);

    char x_str[256];
    char y_str[256];

    fgets(x_str, sizeof(x_str), stdin);
    fgets(y_str, sizeof(y_str), stdin);

    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_init(y);
    mpz_init(result);
    mpz_set_str(x, x_str, 10);
    mpz_set_str(y, y_str, 10);

    switch(op) {
        case '+':
            mpz_add(result, x, y);
            break;
        case '*':
            mpz_mul(result, x, y);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error! operator is not correct");
            break;
    }
    gmp_printf("%Zd", x);
    printf(" %c ", op);
    gmp_printf("%Zd", y);
    gmp_printf(" = %Zd\n", result);

    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_clear(y);
    mpz_clear(result);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and linkk with the library:

```
/tmp$ gcc big.c -lgmp -o big
```

Then run:

```
/tmp$ ./big
Enter the operation: *
99999999
99999999
99999999 * 99999999 = 9999999800000001
```